# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties error

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

enum DeviceType {
    case Phone, Tablet, Watch
}

enum OperatingSystemType {
    case iOS, Android, Windows
}

struct OperatingSystemVersion {
    var Major: Int
    var Minor: Int
    var Patch: Int
}

struct OperatingSystem{
    var type: OperatingSystemType
    var version: OperatingSystemVersion

}

class Device {
    var DeviceID: Int
    var Type: DeviceType
    var Operating_System: OperatingSystem
    var UserID: Int
    var Description: String
    var InventoryNR: String
    init () {
        DeviceID = 1233
        UserID = 2
        Description = "took"
        InventoryNR = "no17"
    }
}
```

// I can't seem to get past this. I just want to create 2 enums, 2 structs and 2 classes

1. Device - Class
   Device Id - Integer
   Type - DeviceType
   Operating System - OperatingSystem
   User Id - Int
   Description - String
   Inventory Number - String

Comment: The error says it all

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html: "Classes and structures *must* set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created." Try initialising `Type` and `Operating_System` in `init()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you returned from `init` without initializing all stored properties.  That's what the problem is.  You need to initialize `Type` and `OperatingSystem` in `init`:

```
init () {
    DeviceID = 1233
    Type = .Phone
    Operating_System = OperatingSystem(type: .iOS, version: OperatingSystemVersion(Major: 9, Minor: 0, Patch: 2))
    UserID = 2
    Description = "took"
    InventoryNR = "no17"
}
```

In the future, please read the error messages before posting.

Comment: I tried to do that and I get that I cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'DeviceType.Type'

Comment: @RoibuAdrian Oops, I messed up a few names.  I fixed it.

Comment: ok, now I understand.. I'm really sorry, I'm new to programming

Comment: @RoibuAdrian That's fine.  For future reference though, we expect lots of research before posting.  That's why you question got so many down votes.  I recommend reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to avoid getting banned from asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

> Initialization
>
> Initialization is the process of preparing an instance
>   of a class, structure, or enumeration for use. This process involves
>   setting an initial value for each stored property on that instance and
>   performing any other setup or initialization that is required before
>   the new instance is ready for use.
>
> You implement this initialization process by defining initializers,
>   which are like special methods that can be called to create a new
>   instance of a particular type. Unlike Objective-C initializers, Swift
>   initializers do not return a value. Their primary role is to ensure
>   that new instances of a type are correctly initialized before they are
>   used for the first time.
>
> Instances of class types can also implement a deinitializer, which
>   performs any custom cleanup just before an instance of that class is
>   deallocated. For more information about deinitializers, see
>   Deinitialization.
>
> **Setting Initial Values for Stored Properties**
>
> **Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.**
>
> **You can set an initial value for a stored property within an
>   initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the
>   property’s definition. These actions are described in the following
>   sections.**
>
> NOTE
>
> When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its
>   initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set
>   directly, without calling any property observers.
>
> Initializers
>
> Initializers are called to create a new instance of a particular type.
>   In its simplest form, an initializer is like an instance method with
>   no parameters, written using the init keyword:
>
> ```
> init() {
>     // perform some initialization here 
> }
> ```
>
> The example below defines a new structure called Fahrenheit to store temperatures expressed in the
>   Fahrenheit scale. The Fahrenheit structure has one stored property,
>   temperature, which is of type Double:
>
> ```
> struct Fahrenheit {
>     var temperature: Double
>     init() {
>         temperature = 32.0
>     } 
> } 
> var f = Fahrenheit() 
> print("The default temperature is \(f.temperature)° Fahrenheit") // prints "The default temperature is 32.0° Fahrenheit"
> ```
>
> The structure defines a single initializer, init, with no parameters, which initializes the stored temperature with a
>   value of 32.0 (the freezing point of water when expressed in the
>   Fahrenheit scale).
>
> Default Property Values
>
> You can set the initial value of a stored property from within an
>   initializer, as shown above. Alternatively, specify a default property
>   value as part of the property’s declaration. You specify a default
>   property value by assigning an initial value to the property when it
>   is defined.
>
> NOTE
>
> If a property always takes the same initial value, provide a default
>   value rather than setting a value within an initializer. The end
>   result is the same, but the default value ties the property’s
>   initialization more closely to its declaration. It makes for shorter,
>   clearer initializers and enables you to infer the type of the property
>   from its default value. The default value also makes it easier for you
>   to take advantage of default initializers and initializer inheritance,
>   as described later in this chapter.
>
> You can write the Fahrenheit structure from above in a simpler form by
>   providing a default value for its temperature property at the point
>   that the property is declared:
>
> ```
> struct Fahrenheit {
>     var temperature = 32.0 
> }
> ```